# Responsive menu not working on blackberry

Tags: mobile, menu, blackberry, joomla2.5

I'm using  the Responsive theme ( Theme Url https://demo.gavick.com/joomla25/simplicity/ ) for one of my site and have used the built-in menu manager (Joomla platform), with everything appearing as should on web and iPhone and android devices.

However, on Blackberry it does not display the 'header-menu', where as all of the other menus - footer, top, etc are appearing fine.

Anyone know what could be going wrong?

FYI - Blackberry Curve 9320.

Comment: It would be handy to see some html and css to work out what the problem might be.

Comment: Theme url https://demo.gavick.com/joomla25/simplicity/

Comment: hi have you checked on iphone devices.Does it display in those devices?

Comment: Yes it is working fine on Iphone and android devices.